# How to load environmental variables when rendering qmd files to html using quarto?

Tags: python, ubuntu, environment-variables, quarto

I'm using Quarto 1.3.450 on Ubuntu 22.04 to render a .qmd file into HTML with Visual Studio extension (my file only contains python code, not R).
It does so by running this command on terminal:

```
quarto preview "my-file.qmd" --to html --no-browser --no-watch-inputs
```

While I'm having no trouble with most things, I got stuck when running a simple

```
os.getenv('variable')
```

If I run this in jupyter notebook is fine. If I run even in quarto, on a code cell, it is also fine. But when rendering, it can't find the variable in my environment. Since it can't find it, I can't properly run my code because the variable becomes empty. It is like quarto used a different environment for rendering. This variable comes from my .env file, which I have `source .env` on terminal. I also check it with `env` and it is there. But when rendering the file, it is not. I don't know what environment Quarto is using. Is there any fix to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer:

When Quarto renders your `.qmd` file, it might not be inheriting the environmental variables from your terminal, especially if they were set only for the session via `source .env`.

To ensure that Quarto gets the necessary environmental variables:

1. **Export Environment Variables Globally**: Instead of sourcing the `.env` file in your terminal session, consider adding the export command to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` file:

   ```bash
   export VARIABLE_NAME=value
   ```

   After adding, you can source your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`:

   ```bash
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```
2. **Pass Environment Variables Explicitly**: When invoking the `quarto` command, you can pass environment variables directly:

   ```bash
   VARIABLE_NAME=value quarto preview "my-file.qmd" --to html --no-browser --no-watch-inputs
   ```

Choose the method that best fits your needs. Option 1 makes the variable available globally, while option 2 is more explicit and contained.